# How to get a value from wp_dropdown_user?

Tags: admin, dashboard

In the admin dashboard, I want to show a list of all users (done so far by wp_dropdown_users) and then take the selected userID and use it as a parameter in another function. :) Sounds easy eh. I've got the dropdown happening, i've got the code to display other info for a selected ID(currently has $output in it..but this could be any userid), just need to know how to attach the two...like how to call the selected user's id and use it.﻿

Current code:

```
function wps_userlist_dw() {

$output = wp_dropdown_users(array(
         'exclude'                 => '1',
         'name'                    => 'author',
         'show'                    => 'ID',
         'echo'                     => true
    ));


$user_info = get_userdata($output);
      echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User level: ' . $user_info->user_level . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
}
```

Any thoughts would be great!

Answer (score 1):

[wp_dropdown_users();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_users) will return users list as select box which is not an array which you can use to get user data, use [get_users();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to get users with their information and make a select box dropdown from.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'exclude' => array(1),
);

$users = get_users( $args );

// now make your users dropdown
if ($users) { ?>
    <select name="my_dropdown">
        <?php foreach ($users as $user) {
            echo '<option value="' .$user->ID .'">' .$user->user_nicename .'</option>';
        } ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}

// now get selected user id from $_POST to use in your next function
$user_id = $_POST['my_dropdown'];

// get user data
$user_data = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

echo $user_data->display_name;
echo $user_data->user_nicename;
echo $user_data->user_email;

// do your stuff using $user_id
```

Comment: Ok, i like using the get_users, that's great.
How do I make the selection translate to the user_id? Is there a need for a button to force the selected user to populate the user_id so that it can show the 'echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";' part?

Sorry for the questions. new to php!!

Comment: @Aaron use `get_user_by('id', $user_id);` to get user data